# PHP extension not built with same debug and thread safe as PHP

Tags: php, php-extension

I built a number of custom PHP extensions under windows 8-10 years ago. I made the move to Ubuntu Linux for all of my web stuff some years ago and find I need to create another custom extension. I'll be doing the development under Ubuntu this time.

I've created a very simple extension (a no-op actually) just to make sure I have the build process working. It's not.

Here is what I have done:

- Cloned PHP from Git
- Checked out PHP-5.5
- Configured with --disable-all --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts \
  --prefix=
- Build PHP
  Success php -i shows:
  Zend Extension Build => API220121212,TS,debug
  PHP Extension Build => API20121212,TS,debug
- Created ext/a1 for my new, very simple extension
- Created the basic extension (from Sara Goleman's book)
- Ran phpize in ext/a1
- Ran ./configure --enable-a1
- Ran make
  Build was successful.
  Copied a1.so to the extensions directory
  phpdir/bin/php -dextension=a1.so -v
  Fails. Results in:
  Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS
  PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,TS,debug

So. Color me confused. According to what I've read, the phpize command is supposed to match the extension build settings to the php build settings.
I've apparently missed something basic here somewhere.

Help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say what exactly was going wrong, I can only say that the extension was build using a different config than the php version.

I will describe some reproducible steps how to compile a most basic extension with debug symbols within the PHP source folder. The extension contains no code except of some boilerplate code created by `ext_skel`. It just describes the compilation process on UNIX. It is a shell script, you might execute it.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Should work for all PHP5 versions
VERSION="5.6.9"

# Download the PHP source code
wget \
    --continue "http://de2.php.net/get/php-$VERSION.tar.gz/from/this/mirror" \
    -O "php-$VERSION".tar.gz

tar xf "php-$VERSION.tar.gz" && cd "php-$VERSION/ext"

# Create a hello extension from skeletons
./ext_skel --extname="hello"

# Uncomment two lines in ext/hello/config.m4
# Read the comments there and you'll know what I'm doing
sed -ri.original \
    -e 's/(dnl )(PHP_ARG_ENABLE\(hello)/\2/' \
    -e 's/(dnl )(\[  --enable-hello)/\2/' \
    hello/config.m4

# Build PHP and the extension
cd ..
./buildconf --force
./configure \
    --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts \
    --enable-hello=shared
make -j

# Test if it is working
sapi/cli/php \
    -dextension=modules/hello.so \
    -r 'var_dump(extension_loaded("hello"));'
```

You can now start to enter code to `ext/hello/hello.c` and create your extension. If you want to compile the changes you make just issue `make` without arguments.

Since we've compiled using `--debug` we you can now use `gdb` to debug the `C` code and explore how PHP internally works. To start a debugging session use:

```
gdb sapi/cli/php
...
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run -dextension=modules/hello.so some.php
```

Of course you'll mostly set breakpoints into your extension functions rather than in the php `main()` function once you've added code to the extension. However, this should show the basic steps to get there.

Have fun! :)

```
gdb
```

Comment: Hmm. Black magic ensues, apparently ;-)
So, I do that in my extension source dir?

Comment: Yes, in the extension source dir. I assume that you have compiled php with `--enable-debug` in `/path/to/php-source` before. (This would create the right `php-config` script). If not, do it.

Comment: configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-debug

configure: error: Cannot find php-config. Please use --with-php-config=PATH  

I have confirmed the path to php-config and tried both with and without the php-config filename.

Comment: You are right the `enable-debug` option is not necessary (and wrong) when configuring the extension. The `--with-php-config` is important. Where did you build php in debugging mode? (In which folder?)

Comment: PHP sources are in /Volumes/Data01/VMShares/PhpDevelopment/php-src-55 and that is where I built PHP.  
My extension is in /Volumes/Data01/VMShares/PhpDevelopment/php-src-55/ext/a1 and that is where I ran phpize and configure.

Comment: Let's use [`chat`](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/79854/compile-php-extension?tab=general)